# Java: Calling non-static method with this. from static method

Tags: java

I was wondering if I could use this. to call a non-static method from within a static method. I know I would need an object in general to reference to a non-static method from within a static method. Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? Were you able to do it?

Answer (score 3):

No. Within a static method, `this` has no meaning and will not compile. This is covered by [§8.4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2) of the Java Language Specification, although it should be fairly intuitive — what would `this`refer to?

You *can* call non-static methods from static methods, just not via `this`. You have to have an instance on which to call them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "this" keyword in a static method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. A static method is not associated with an instance of the class, so it cannot access a non static variable or method of the same class that has a meaning only if there is an instance of the class

Answer (score 0):

Not using `this`, but if you really wanted to, if the class was named `MyClass`, you could do

```
new MyClass().someNonStaticMethod()
```

But if you're calling instance methods like this, they should probably be static anyway.